# Using self.rect.centerx in pygame to move character at random

Tags: python, pygame

Currently I cannot get the chracater to move with each iteration of the if statement like he should. Every second the character should move 100 pixels but just moves once at the beginning of the cycle. When I include the statement self.rect.centerx = (WIDTH*3/4) the character doesn't move at all from his postion. When I don't include self.rect.centerx = (WIDTH*3/4) the chracter jumps to the other side of the screen. I cannot move my rect statement around much or I will get an error saying rect is not an attribute of TRUMP class. Please advise.

```
class TRUMP(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.game = game
    self.current_frame2 = 0
    self.last_update2 = 0
    self.load_images()
    self.update()
    self.image = self.TRUMP_fingers_l

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH *3/4), (589)
    self.rect.centerx = (WIDTH*3/4)
    self.rect.centery = 589
    self.pos = vec((WIDTH/2), (HEIGHT/2))
    self.vel = vec(0, 0)
    self.acc = vec(0, 0)

    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

 def update(self):
    now = pg.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update2 > 1000:
    self.last_update2 = now
    self.current_frame2 = (self.current_frame2 + 1) % len(self.TRUMP_walk_cycle)
    self.image = self.TRUMP_walk_cycle[self.current_frame2]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = (WIDTH*3/4)
    self.rect.centerx -= 100
    print(self.rect.centerx)
    self.rect.centery = 589
```

Comment: Please show us your code as it runs on your system. The code you show here has bad indentation and will not run. Just copy-and-paste from your editor into the site's editor, highlight your code, and press `ctrl-K` or click the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: I don't know how to format in this window. I am on mac and don't know what ctrl-k is equivalent to. I get an error when I try and past it all.

Comment: Why is your class called TRUMP? (Love it by the way)

Comment: @MattMacy As Rory said: you can use `ctrl-k` **or** the `{}` button when editing your question. Or you can manually add four spaces for every indention.

Comment: I am making a game where your character battles Donald trump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new rect at 0, 0 (`self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`) and then use the exact same values to change it's position every update. What you can do is use the previous rect's position, initialize the new rect and then increment the position. Like so:

```
def update(self):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update > 250:
        self.last_update = now
        self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.TRUMP_walk_cycle)
        self.image = self.TRUMP_walk_cycle[self.current_frame]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        self.rect.centerx -= 30
```

If your images are the same sizes you don't even have to create a new rectangle. You could just use your old:

```
def update(self):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update > 250:
        self.last_update = now
        self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.TRUMP_walk_cycle)
        self.image = self.TRUMP_walk_cycle[self.current_frame]
        self.rect.centerx -= 30
```

Comment: I am having a hard time with self.rect = self.image.get_rect(). The program wants to say the TRUMP object has no attribute for it. I have self.rect.centerx - 30 and it does not work.

Comment: That's odd... And the code in the question is as in your program? Because you have defined `self.image` and `self.rect` so it shouldn't give any attribute error. What does the error message say?

Comment: AttributeError: 'TRUMP' object has no attribute 'rect' Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Sometimes you get weird errors if you have wrong indentions or misspell names wrong. You didn't call `self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)` before you initialized `self.rect`, right? You didn't change any code in your `__init__` method?

Comment: self.rect comes first yes

Comment: So is your code *exactly* as the one in the question or have you changed anything in the `update` or `__init__` method? The error means that you haven't initialized `self.rect` before you're trying to call it or that misspelled names or wrong indentions makes the error being faulty raised. If you haven't changed your code from what you have in the question, it's a possibility the error is being caused by other code in your program. Also, your question have indention errors but I assume they're not in your actual code and you just haven't edit the question yet, or do your code have it too?

Comment: My code is correctly formatted and I have changed anything in the update or __init__method. I currently am not getting the error. The only problem is I can't  seem to get self.rect.centerx -= 30 functioning.

Comment: If you've changed your code I cannot help you since I don't know what you've changed. You can edit your question and put in your current code instead (since posting code in the comments is unreadable) and I'll see if I can find the problem. Notice that my code isn't using exactly the same variables as your program, so you have to change them accordingly.

Comment: I get these value printed for my X and Y repeating:                                    77 140
77 140
61 139
77 140
77 140
61 139

Comment: I can't guess the problem on that information since I don't know what code you currently have. I see now you call `self.update()` before you initialize `self.rect` which is why you got the attribute error, but since you're not getting it anymore I assume you've fixed it. Don't call any methods in the `__init__` method until all attributes used in that method are initialized. Remove `self.update()` or put it at the bottom of the `__init__` method.

Comment: You were right! I got rid of self.update and self.rect = self.image.get_rect() and now the character stays in the same place! Thank!

Comment: Consider marking the answer with an accept mark if it helped you, to indicate that this question is solved. It'd be much appreciated if you did this for your other questions as well, or that you leave a comment on the answers that didn't solve the question so that they can try fix their answer.